# Change image in gallery

Tags: android

I have a gallery where I'm displaying a number of ID cards as images.
When the user clicks on an image, I want to change the image to another one which shows the 'back' of the card.

I have bound an arraylist of objects to the gallery, each object contains the front and back images.

I have two image views, one for the front and one for the back image. The gallery will initially show all front images ( the 'back' image view visibility is set to GONE). My idea was to change the visibility of the relevant image view when the user clicks.

That's about as far as I've got, buy I'm not sure how to implement the click functionality to change the views.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can't change directly the views in an adapterview (which gallery is). You need to change the data itself, for example by adding a boolean field, and acting on it in your getView method.

Comment: Thanks. Could you expand some more on what you mean please?

Comment: I assume you have a gallery and an adapter? in the adapter, you handle objects to render a view (in getview)? then you need to add something in the object you handle to indicate the checked status of the object.

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry if I'm not getting this (it's been a long day :)). So, I only use one image view, and update a Boolean in the object to indicate whether the front or back should be displayed? If that's the case, how do I trigger the update? (As you can probably tell, the gallery is new to me!)

Comment: you modify the value in the array used in your adapter (probably an ArrayAdapter?) and call notifyDatasetChanged on your adapter.

Comment: Super. Thanks, I'll give that a go. Do you want to stick your reply into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: If that works and solves your issue, tell me, and I'll format it so it can be an actual answer.

Comment: Will do. Hopefully early tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked well, so go ahead with the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Gallery` is a specialization of `AdapterView`, which also contains `ListView`, `Spinner`,  `GridView`... All of these have in common to display n times the same 'kind' of view with different data.

These particular views use an `Adapter` to handle the view creation and population process. The `getView` method is called on the adapter, providing this class with the data for creating the view for a particular row (cell, gallery item ...).

The `getView` method is called when the `AdapterView` deems it necessary, and the developer has no control on which view gets created or when it does.

Therefore, it is practically impossible to modify a child of the `AdapterView` directly. It would result it the modification being arbitrarily overwritten, or even transferred to another row of the view.

Instead, to act on the child views, it is necessary to act on the data that are used to populate the view. (Note that this enforce the MVC model, as the view remains a reflection of the model, rather than being manipulated by the controller.)

In this particular example, the view is to display a different image based on the `checked` status of the data. To achieve that, add a `checked` member to the model :

```
public class MyModel {
    // ... Other members
    public boolean checked = false;
}
```

Use that value in getView :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, View parent) {
    MyModel current = getItem(position);
    // ... Inflate and populate
    if (current.checked) {
        // Specific checked behavior
    } else {
        // Not checked behavior
    }
}
```

The `checked` value is to be modified in the controller, probably a `OnItemClickListener`:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // Here, there can be several ways to access the clicked item.
    // I assume myAdapter is the adapter used for the gallery
    MyModel current = myAdapter.get(position);
    current.checked = !current.checked;
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```